# Hibernate version jars, maven, what should go together?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have trouble understanding what jar versions should go together for hibernate.

I have a set of hibernate versions maven things that work together, but I don't know why, how can I work out what versions work with what other versions?

Also I want to upgrade my hibernate, but I don't know what version numbers to put in or if I require the other ones.

Currently I have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. This process is unnecessarily complicated. Take a look at the [Compatibility Matrix](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix) to find out which versions of the libraries you need.

Also, from 3.5.x, [Annotations and Hibernate EntityManager are part of Hibernate Core](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/ClarificationAboutAnnotationsAndEntityManager).

Comment: "are part of Hibernate Core" only refers to downloads from the Hibernate download site. If using Maven you still need to have each separate jar, but they'll all have the same version number.