# Can one .war file be built with both 8.4 and 9.0 postgres (hibernate) libraries?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, maven

We've been using maven dependencies to specify the libraries so far, i.e.:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>8.4-702.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

However, we are now running the exact same .war file on different machines, and would like to keep the same One-war-file-to-rule-them-all, but don't want to hit issues by using an older driver on a postgres 9.1 installation (especially when byte array encoding defaults have changed, for example). Cliff-Claven esque like information that probably won't matter but added anyway: OS for both of these installations are Mac OS X Server, the Postgres 8.4 one is running on 10.6, the 9.1 one is running on 10.7. We have no need to upgrade any data (separate instances started from scratch).

Perhaps it's more of a maven question than anything else, but I couldn't seem to see anything specific to my situation. I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595118/hibernate-version-jars-maven-what-should-go-together), but it's older Hibernate 3.5 which doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: Quick tip, not really related to your question: `postgresql` dependency should have `runtime` scope anyway, since it's used at run-time. If you don't need `hibernate-c3p0` for compilation, it should also has `runtime` scope.

Comment: You can simply bundle the new driver for both versions. There is no problem connecting to 8.4 using the 9.1 driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For PostgreSQL, the latest version of the JDBC driver should be used regardless of the version of the server, except for truly extremely ancient versions.

http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html#current says:

> This is the current version of the driver. Unless you have unusual
>   requirements (running old applications or JVMs), this is the driver
>   you should be using. It supports Postgresql 7.2 or newer and requires
>   a 1.4 or newer JVM.

For the PostgreSQL JDBC driver, as bugs are fixed and features added they generally go only into the latest version.  Newer JDBC driver versions are aware of older server versions and will behave correctly according to the server version.

Note that older JDBC drivers are *not* aware of newer server versions, and in fact you can cause security problems by using a JDBC driver older than the server version.

Comment: I wish I could +2 this because I feel like this answers 2 questions :) 1. How to support multiple versions of PostgreSQL and 
2. Which driver version should you choose

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understood your question. I have a slightly different take on this problem. Here are my comments/suggestions:

1. Instead of bundling the driver related jars directly into the war file, **use a datasource** managed by the application server (tomcat etc)
2. This way there **won't be any dependency** of the war on the driver class.
3. The datasource configuration can be done on the app server and your web application just **needs to know its JNDI name** for looking it up.
4. This will also in tune with your **One-war-file-to-rule-them-all** approach as the war file will be truly independent of any driver related dependencies.

The *drawback* with this approach is that the drivers jars needs to be maintained manually on app server but its just one time task and completely detached from any application level changes.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would probably be to put the jdbc driver into a shared lib folder on the server and not package it inside the war. This can be done by setting the scope to `provided`.

You could define build profiles in your pom with different dependency versions, but that would require invoking the build two times and result in two different war files.

Comment: For PostgreSQL, the latest version of the JDBC driver should be used regardless of the version of the server, except for truly extremely ancient versions.  http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html#current  "This is the current version of the driver. Unless you have unusual requirements (running old applications or JVMs), this is the driver you should be using. It supports Postgresql 7.2 or newer and requires a 1.4 or newer JVM."